# PHP & XML: str_replace does NOT replace string

Tags: php, xml, replace

I got the following code:

```
$xmlString = file_get_contents([...]);
$echoMe= str_replace( 'ZONE', 'ENOZ', $xmlString);
echo $echoMe;
```

How come it still shows me ZONE right there when I echo it?

Comment: `$xmlString` & `$xmlstring` ~ two different variables

Comment: ugh, forgot to change it on the 2nd line to add the camel-case-style. In my script, it's 1:1 the same, just with a different name...edited now.

Comment: Sample source just for local testing?

Comment: https://eval.in/500488 The example works, the problem is not str_replace().